# Cross-browser way of avoiding unresponsive script

Tags: javascript

I would like to avoid unresponsive javascript in all browsers.
Is it possible to write code with that in mind?

DETAILS: Problem is that currently there is a potential script block that executes fine in Chrome on my PC, but causing problems on IE (various versions). The worst thing is that I really don't know for sure if it is that script block at all. I will rewrite and solve that. However, I would like to know **what exactly I should be avoiding** while coding. This...

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-execution-browser-limits/

...is an interesting read but it's too general.

**EDIT**: I'm using jQuery/jQueryUI as well.

**EDIT 2**: There are patterns/principles to use to avoid particular problems. E.g. singleton pattern, PRG pattern, DRY principle... and such. Is there something like that for this kind of problem?

Comment: What are you doing that is causing it to become unresponsive, you could consider using webworkers or delegating it to a function that runs say 1 one tenth a time and execute the function with the setInterval() method?

Comment: If you want to close this question, please explain why. According to help this is a legitimate question: I want to know exactly what to do.

Comment: @FraserK: I can't use webworker because of IE9 support. There is a code block that performs ajax call and on response changes states of various jQueryUI buttons and eventually initializes other stuff via jQuery. I will solve that. I just want to know when I next time write a JS code block, can I have some direction where exactly to look for problems? With cross-browser support in mind.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What does "causing problems" mean?

Comment: @Guffa: it is in my question: unresponsive javascript is the problem. Browser raises the information that JS execution is unresponsive and user can choose to stop it.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić When writing scripts in JS avoid using while(true) loops unless you know exectuion will be short and avoid long loops. Note the the jQuery .each can cause the browser to lock up with too many items. For time when you need to work on 1000's of items set up a setInterval function so that the thread can yielf to the browser.

Comment: That wasn't in the question. That means that the browser is not just unresponsive from time to time, it means that the script is running for a very long time. That usually means that you have an infinite loop, that you should be able to pinpoint by adding a few debug messages in the code.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into problems like this before as well.

The thing to keep in mind as you code, is *where does my code begin execution*, and *where does my code end execution*. For all of the time between those two points, the browser's UI thread is blocked, and the browser makers have understandably developed counter measures.

As far as *what to avoid*, avoid long, continuous loops.

Here's an extreme example:

```
function howManyMultiplesOfFourBelow(foo) {
   var i = 0, j = 0;
   while (i < foo) {
      i++;
      if (i % 4 === 0) {
         j++;
      }
   }
   return j;
}
```

If you pass 10,000,000 to that function, IE will definitely throw a fit. There is more than one way to program around this kind of situation; what I prefer is to break up the code using `setTimeout`/`setInterval`. After setting an interval and returning out of a function, we release the UI thread back to the browser, and the browser is in charge of executing the interval as often as we've requested (or as often as it is able).

I combine this with [Futures/Promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises); In particular, [jQuery's implementation](http://api.jquery.com/promise/).
Using this style, the above example could be rewritten not to block the UI thread during the calculation by leveraging promises, and `setInterval`.

```
function howManyMultiplesOfFourBelow(foo) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        interval,
        i = 0,
        j = 0;

    interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (i >= foo) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            deferred.resolve(j);
            return;
        }
        i++;
        if (i % 4 === 0) {
           j++;
        }
    }, 1);

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

The first important difference is that this function no longer returns the answer, but instead a *promise* of an answer. So, consuming code might look like this:

```
howManyMultiplesOfFourBelow(10000000).done(function (multiples) {
    //Update the DOM with the answer (multiples)
});
```

Returning to your question more generally, think about how much of your code *must* be run continuously, and if any of it could be delayed, or broken up in order to release the UI thread briefly.

Comment: This is a good point (upvote), and a great reference to future/promise pattern (offtopic - someone should write a future/promise vs. delegate comparison). Your answer definitely alleviates a part of the problem. However, it doesn't solve the problem generally. If there would be a checklist for this it would be great. Maybe a tool (e.g. profiler-based) that would run JS script and pinpoint the problem. I don't know where exactly to look for solution that would erradicate this kind of a problem from an existing or newly written code.